# Javascript Bookmarklet to change the URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Let's say the structure of the page URL is `http://string.static.com/*`

`string` may vary but will only consist of any combination of alphanumeric characters and dashes.

`static.com` is self-explanatory.

`*` could be anyting containing letters, numbers, /,:,? and similar characters, so basically there can be directories and parameters as well.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

The bookmarklet should replace everyting after `.com/...` so the url becomes `http://string.static.com/archive`

I've created two (very similar) JS bookmarklets so far but I can't wrap my head around this one. It should be fairly simple but I haven't had any luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `location.origin+"/"+ strWhatever`

Comment: simple enough to figure out by inspecting the `window.location` object ....`console.dir(location)` then reverse engineer what you need